# Ruby flexible client class with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, api, request, httparty

I usually use the Faraday gem to connect to the external API but I want to try HTTParty for my pure Ruby app. The idea is to build flexible client class, similar to this one from made with Faraday:

```
  class Client
    API_ENDPOINT = 'https://id.amiqus.co/api/'
    PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['personal_access_token']

    def initialize
      @access_token = PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
    end

    def get(path, options = {})
      client.public_send(:get, path.to_s, options)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client =
        Faraday.new(API_ENDPOINT) do |client|
          client.request :url_encoded
          client.response :json, content_type: /\bjson$/
          client.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
          client.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
          client.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
          client.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{access_token}" if access_token.present?
        end
    end
```

How to build that memoization `client` method using HTTParty?

Answer (score -1):

```
    private

def request(method, endpoint, params={} )
  HTTParty.public_send(
    method,
    endpoint,
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': TOKEN},
    body: params.to_json
  )
end
```

Comment: Please describe what this does and how it will help the OP solve their problem/answer their question.